# Check for Changes on a Email Signature

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have received a odd request.

I have done my own Research I just cant seem to find alot in regards to the topic.

So im wondering if anyone knows or has a way to check for or Refresh Email Signatures.

I realize this might be a bit of topic if so Can someone guide me a spot where I can ask?

I was thinking of pointing to a URL and then updating it on the URL but that would require someone to check the URL everyday, I just cant think of a way to have the Signature check for Automatic updates.

Just to add a little more clarification: The Signature would need to update daily. So it would either have to fetch from a URL everyday or check for changes

Comment: What email program are you using? If you're wanting to automatically update an Outlook desktop email signature, you can't.  You'd have to do this manually. But if you use an ESP like Mailchimp (or any other) you may be able to either generate a new email every time you need it, or use something like a webhook or API to pull that data in dynamically

Comment: Thats the problem It'll have to work with anything, As one of my first thoughts was using something like the outlook API to just. pull and add to the signature

Comment: It will have to work with anything? This is not a question StackOverflow can answer, as it seems like such a question would have to deal with "any" and every API known to humanity. You need to choose something more specific

Comment: Apologies I thought you'd gather from your own & the questions context, That by anything I meant Any of the Common Mailing Systems. EG Gmail, Oulook, Mailer Not to sure what els there is but Im guessing it'll mostly be Outlook/Mailer & Mobile Mailing applications, But hey I mean if I can get this to work on a Lightbulb that would make a interesting system. 
I'm more just looking for clarification on weather Commonly used email programs like Outlook | Gmail | Mailer(Mac) can have automated email signatures as form my understanding you cant use anything but html and css in mailers

Comment: Okay, so AFAIK the only way this **might** be possible (havne't tried) is through some kind of RPA mechanism, where a script runs that can click on your screen and insert things and interpret graphics (and pulls data from some source to insert). Gmail/Outlook/Apple Mail and such are not geared for this out of the box. Each would have to be setup individually - that's why I say it needs to be more specific. Only bulk mail providers like MailChimp have variables that can be dynamic in this way.